# Will a drone placed in a vacuum chamber still fly?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, fluid-dynamics

Any flying object (plane or helicopter) uses lift from the air to move off from the ground. Will it still lift in a vacuum?

Comment: [Experiment already done](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=g8-pxkaipcg)

Answer (score 3):

Airplanes, helicopters, drones etc all fly (produce lift) by displacing air downwards - so none of them could fly in a vacuum (neither could a bird or insect, even if provided with a tiny respirator).